# set complete+=k[file] not working for whole line completion?

Tags: vim

I have `~/.bash_history` that contains lines such as `sudo apt-get install`, `aplay foo.wav`, etc. I thought it would be convenient if I could use these lines for completing whole lines while writing shell scripts.

`:h compl-whole-line` says:

> CTRL-X CTRL-L
>   Search backwards for a line that starts with the
>             same characters as those in the current line before
>             the cursor.  Indent is ignored.  The matching line is
>             inserted in front of the cursor.
>             ** The 'complete' option is used to decide which buffers
>             are searched for a match.  Both loaded and unloaded
>             buffers are used.**

Note the asterisks I inserted. `:h 'complete'` says:

```
 k      k{dict} scan the file {dict}.  Several "k" flags can be given,
        patterns are valid too.  For example: >
        :set cpt=k/usr/dict/*,k~/spanish
```

So I thought `:set complete+=k~/.bash_history` would do the job. It didn't.

Start vim with

```
$ vim -u NONE -N
```

then

```
:set complete+=k~/.bash_history
:set complete?
" complete=.,w,b,u,t,i,k~/.bash_history
```

, I enter to the insert mode (`i`), and when I type

```
su<C-x><C-l>
```

, vim says `Whole line completion (^L^N^P) Pattern not found`. The completion is working for words, so when I type

```
su<C-p>
```

`sudo` is suggested.

What am I missing? How can I use my history for whole line completion without `:sp ~/.bash_history`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set complete+=k[file]` has nothing to do with line completion: whatever file you give to it will only be used as a source by *dictionary completion* (`<C-x><C-k>`) and *keyword completion* (`<C-n>`/`<C-p>`).

`:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-l` is clear: line completion only works with **lines found in loaded and unloaded buffers.** Since `~/.bash_history` is not loaded as a buffer, line completion will obviously *never* use it as a source.

So yes, the only *practical* solution is to load that file.

`:sp ~/.bash_history` is not really optimal, though, because a) it takes too much room, both physically and in your buffer list, and b) it requires way too many keystrokes.

The *"too much room"* part of the problem is easily solved with a more suited command:

```
:badd ~/.bash_history
```

The *"too many keystrokes"* part of the problem could be solved with an autocommand that runs the command above each time you edit a shell script:

```
augroup shell
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.sh badd ~/.bash_history
augroup END
```

Comment: +n for `:badd`, it seems very practical. I'm a little confused by the part "'complete' option is used to decide which buffers are searched for a match", though --- which options of `complete` can actually affect the whole line completion?

Comment: Whole line completion uses loaded and unloaded *buffers* so buffer-related options apply: `.,w,b,u,U`. Note that `:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-l` and `:help 'complete'` don't agree with each other on the subject of unloaded buffers. The former says "Both loaded and unloaded buffers are used." while the latter says "Unloaded buffers are not scanned for whole-line completion." The former is provably right and the latter is provably wrong.